# Is there a correct way of comparing two different 'scales' of the same range?

Tags: scales

Is there a correct way of comparing two different scales (for example; data which comes from a 4 option question and data which comes from a 7 option question) given that both datasets have the same range (for example; both the 4 option and 7 option question represent a numerical scale from 0 to 100%). The easiest option would just be to convert each dataset into the numerical representation on the scale of 0-100. I know this isn't exactly preferable but is it valid?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you comparing questions? Or answers to the questions?